# Зачем умножать на 100 в random?

Tags: python-3.x

Я создаю список из 20 элементов, создаваемых функцией random. Почему, если не умножать random на 100, то выдаются все двадцать нулей, а если умножить на 100, то уже рандом работает нормально?

```
for i in range(N):
    array.append(int(random()*100))
```

Answer (score 6):

Дело в том, что `random()` 
выдает псевдо-случайное число в интервале [0;1).
Но (как отметил @Sergey Gornostaev) при выполнении `int(x)` - дробная часть x отпадает. В результате остается только 0.
Теперь, умножим random на 100. В результате будет псевдо-случайное число в интервале [0*100,1*100) <=> [0,100). Учтите, что результатом всё также будет дробное число! (к примеру 51,264792). Правда дробный "хвост" обрезается после применения `int()`.

Аналогично можно получить рандом в любом диапазоне. Например, чтобы получить рандомное число в диапазоне [0,4) нужно просто умножить `random` на 4. А для [5,9) достаточно просто прибавить к предыдущему результату 5.

Кроме того, если интересуют только целые числа, есть функция `random.randint(a, b)`,
которая вернёт целое число a<=x<=b

Answer (score 1):

используй функцию `random.randint(10, 100)`, если тебе требуется получить случайное целое число в диапазоне от 10 до 100.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте выполнить `random()`. Получите что-нибудь вроде `0.23554982441483208`. Теперь попробуйте конвертировать это в целое число: `int(0.23554982441483208)`. Дробная часть будет отброшена и получите 0. А теперь попробуйте умножить результат `random` на 100: `0.23554982441483208 * 100`.